# Fixed top menu bar

Tags: ios, menu

I'd like to implement a top menu bar in an iOS app. I want it to be shown in every view controller. Whats the best approach besides using the bar from the navigation controller?

Comment: If you want it in every view controller than you should use tabbar controller not the top menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built in functionalities for iOS that allow you to have UI persist amongst many view controllers. Currently the UITabBarController and the UISplitViewController contain views at the bottom or left and persist among the other view controllers that are linked to be displayed. The UINavigationcontroller has a view at the top. If you wanted something else, then there is no standard iOS way of doing it, but here are 3 options.

1. Create a master view controller class that all class inherit from this one. Have what ui you would like to persist recreated via a singleton and added as a subview when you allocate the master class.
2. The top bar could be added as a subview to the UINavigationController. Subclass uinavigationcontroller and you can do `[self.view addSubview:view]`.
3. Or add the ui to the window of the app. This can be done anywhere through out the app all you need to do is `UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
   [keyWindow addSubview:view];`

I would suggest going with option 2, option 1 is too tedious for something so simple and option 3 would persist through out the entirety of the app, option 2 associates the view you add with the UINavigationController, therefore only the view controller in the navigation controller are affected, like wise if you remove the navigation controller the content goes with it.